# Populating Combo box in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**controller.js**

```
$scope.buildings={};

for (var i=0;i<$scope.buildingObj.length;i++){
        $scope.buildings.building=$scope.buildingObj[i].building;
        console.log($scope.buildings.building);
}
```

In console am able to print $scope.buildings.building. Now I want to populate $scope.buildings in a combobox.

**EDIT**

$scope.buildings gives

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

$scope.buildings.building gives as below

```
Tidel
Ascendas
Sun-Tech
```

How can I do this? Am new to AngularJS. pls help me get through this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select>
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="l in buildings" value="{{l}}">{{l.building}}</option>

  </select>
```

Where your display will contain building name and value would be object which you could use on server side, or it could be l.building only if you directly want building name as value of selected option

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tInZEPLXokb9NkqGk2so?p=preview

Comment: I am getting undefined in combo box. buildings has list of objects. Inside for loop in controller, buildings.building gives me building name. similarly how can I do this in combo box in html?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of buildings.building object so it would help more in answering?

Comment: now am getting the --Select-- and the last value in the list, that is Sun-Tech. I want all three along with Select. :(

Comment: I have updated the answer please check plunker link also @Kaushi

Comment: Welcome :) @Kaushi

Answer (score 0):

You could have a autocomplete textbox that will have textbox for the input and dropdownlist for search reference.

Below is the link : 
http://csharpimp.blogspot.in/2016/03/angular-material-auto-complete.html